# Faster way to find an element that is in only one set?

Tags: python

I'd like to iterate through a **list of sets** and find any sets with a number that is unique/**doesn't** appear in any other sets in the list.

**Note** that this list of set is representing a row in a sudoku board and each set represents the options. If there is only a single element, it represents the number at that location on board.

In the following code, I define a function that can check if a set has a number that doesn't appear in another set in this list. **However**, this is wasteful and since I will check each set in the list that has more than one element in it.

How can I change this/what can I use that will allow me to perform this operation multiple times in a less expensive manner?

```py
def find_unique(sudoku_options, check_index):
    comparison_set = set()

    for i in range(len(sudoku_options)):
        if i != check_index:
            comparison_set.update(list(sudoku_options[i]))
    for S in sudoku_options:
        for item in S:
            if not item in comparison_set:
                return item
    return -1
```

The following is simple testing code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    row1 = [{1}, {3}, {5}, {6}, {8}, {9}, {4,7}, {4,7}, {2,4,7}]
    x = find_unique(row1, 8)
    print(x)
    #Output: 2 (as desired)
```

Thanks for all and any of your help!

Comment: Create a union of all the sets and check if your number is not in that?

Comment: @tripleee That will waste some memory tho. Suppose we have `{2}` to check from and we supply `({2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8})` as the ones to check from. If we loop through the sets, we can immediately tell that the result will be empty. (Btw, creating a union of a large number of sets is time-consuming too. Check out number 6 in https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

Comment: If this is a sudoku board, the whole full set will be 9 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `defaultdict` and for each value keep list of sets in which it belongs. Then find elements that belongs to one set.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import typing

def find_sets_with_unique_elements(set_list: typing.List[typing.Set]):
    counter = defaultdict(list)
    for i, el in enumerate(set_list):
        for val in el:
            counter[val].append(i)
    return [(sets[0], val) for val, sets in counter.items() if len(sets) == 1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    row1 = [{1}, {3}, {5}, {6}, {8}, {9}, {4,7}, {4,7}, {2,4,7}]
    x = find_sets_with_unique_elements(row1)
    print(x)
```

Comment: @Blonded I approve partial your edit. the variable started with underscore should not be reused. This is python convention

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler by using this:

```py
# Note that this returns a set of all unique elements.
# Getting all of the numbers keeps you from calling
# the function multiple times until you get a -1
# instead of iterating through the set that's returned.

def find_unique(check, *other):
    # `check` is the set to find a unique element from
    # `*other` is the tuple of sets to compare against

    check = check.copy() # Get a copy

    for set_ in other:
        # This will remove an element that is in both
        # `check` and `set_` and will remove it from
        # `check`.
        check -= set_

        # Early exit condition (where `check` is empty)
        if not check:
            break

    return check
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your initial idea is to return the **first** unique item from a set in target position (as seen in your initial function):

```
def find_unique(sudoku_options, check_index):
    if check_index >= len(sudoku_options):
        raise IndexError(f'Index {check_index} is out of range')
    lst_copy = sudoku_options.copy()
    lst_copy.pop(check_index)   # exclude target set from list copy

    for num in sudoku_options[check_index]:
        if num not in set.union(*lst_copy):
            return num
    return -1

row1 = [{1}, {3}, {5}, {6}, {8}, {9}, {4,6}, {4,6}, {2,4,6}]
x = find_unique(row1, 8)
print(x)   # 2
x = find_unique(row1, 4)
print(x)   # 8
x = find_unique(row1, 3)
print(x)   # -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, 2x enhancement could be achieved as follows:

```py
In [19]: row1[8].difference(reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), row1[:8], set() ))                  
Out[19]: {2}

In [20]: %timeit row1[8].difference(reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), row1[:8], set() ))          
4.7 µs ± 105 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit find_unique(row1, 8)                                                           
8.32 µs ± 71 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**EDIT**: Removed unnecessary reduce :D for ~6x enhancement

```py
In [9]: %timeit row1[8].difference(set.union(*row1[:8]))                                        
1.42 µs ± 109 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you are looking for:

```
def find_unique(sudoku_options, check_index):
    sets_to_check = sudoku_options[:]
    check_set = sets_to_check.pop(check_index)

    all_numbers = set().union(*sets_to_check)
    return check_set - all_numbers

if __name__ == "__main__":
    row1 = [{1}, {3}, {5}, {6}, {8}, {9}, {4,7}, {4,7}, {2,4,7}]
    x = find_unique(row1, 8)
    for number in x:
        print(number)
```